# Disable auto build/sync when a new activity is created in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

Whenever I create a new activity the Android Studio keeps syncing and building it. I have configured my builds to a remote server as I am running out of resources on the work machine. Hence I don't want Android Studio to compile code on creation of an activity, How do I disable this feature of Android Studio?

Comment: not perfect solution but , if you create class and layout separately then it wont compile.

Comment: have you found out the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Don't create activity directly from android studio menu. Create the activity java class, layout separately, therefore, it will not build it again. If you follow this way then you need to manually mention your activity java class file name in the Manifest file.

Comment: This is not solution.